# Configure web.config to redirect non-www requests to www for multi-site Drupal 7 Install

Tags: redirection, multi-sites, .htaccess

I have a multi-site Drupal 7 install running on Azure that I would like to force all non-www traffic to the www address for all sites.

I have tried a number of examples from around the web but none of them seem to work.

Here is my current implementation, which looks like it should work, but does nothing.

```
<rule name="Redirect to www">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

To clarify, yes, the above rule is nested inside `<configuration> <system.webServer> <rewrite>`

I've read about doing the redirect in settings.php but that seems kludgy to me and I'd rather do it right.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some subtle differences between this and the rule above, but this officially works for my multi-site Drupal install on Azure IIS.

```
<rule name="WWW Rewrite" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.(.*)$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```